# Too late to create Fragments?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am working on my first Android application. I just came to discover Fragments and I need them to create a ViewPager to create nice transitions between my activities, but I fear that it's too late to implement that.

I have to put all my code (`MainActivity`) in my MainFragment? Or just some pieces   I don't know what I have to keep in my `MainActivity`

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ObjectAnimator anim;
    ObjectAnimator anim2;
    private int display, result, detect = 0;
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    private ImageButton nfcButton;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private ImageButton qrButton;
    private TextView text;
    private SlidrInterface slidr;
    private ImageButton webButton;
    float x1, x2, y1, y2;
    String link = null;
    public final int CUSTOMIZED_REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000ffff;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        slidr = Slidr.attach(this);
        setDetect(1);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main);
        this.text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        this.nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        this.nfcButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nfc_button);
        this.anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.nfcButton, "scaleX", new float[]{0.9f});
        this.anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.nfcButton, "scaleY", new float[]{0.9f});
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        this.nfcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDisplay(1);
                manageBlinkEffect();
            }
        });
        this.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {                                   // RESULTAT DU SCAN QR CODE
        if (requestCode != CUSTOMIZED_REQUEST_CODE && requestCode != IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CUSTOMIZED_REQUEST_CODE: {
                Toast.makeText(this, "REQUEST_CODE = " + requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }

        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(resultCode, data);

        if (result.getContents() != null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Résultat du scan :");
            if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(result.getContents())) {                                                                      // si url...
                builder.setNeutralButton("Visiter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Fermer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Copier", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Texte copié", result.getContents());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                    }
                });
            } else {                                                                                                             // si plain text...
                builder.setNeutralButton("Copier", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Texte copié", result.getContents());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Fermer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
            }
            builder.setMessage(result.getContents().toString());
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }


    public void manageBlinkEffect() {                                                                           // ANIMATION DU LOGO SENZU SUITE A UN CLIC
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(9);
        anim.start();
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
                if (getRes() != 1){
                    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aucun badge n'a été détécté !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    nfcButton.startAnimation(shake);
                }
            }
        });
        anim2.setDuration(1000);
        anim2.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        anim2.setRepeatCount(9);
        anim2.start();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent(); // Recuperer l'intent actuel
        NdefMessage[] msgs;
        if (getDetect() == 1 && (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))) { // si l'application a ete lancee via une detection NFC du device  (ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, voir AndroidManifest)
            Parcelable[] rawMessages =
                    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES");
            if (rawMessages != null) { // si NDEF dans le scan
                setDisplay(1);
                resolveIntent(intent); // parser le scan NFC
            }  else {
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
                Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                byte[] payload = NdefMessageParser.dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {record});
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] {msg};
                setDetect(0);
                getResult(msgs);
            }
        }
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter2 = this.nfcAdapter;
        if (nfcAdapter2 != null) {
            if (!nfcAdapter2.isEnabled()) {
                showWirelessSettings();
            }
            this.nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, this.pendingIntent, (IntentFilter[]) null, (String[][]) null);
        }
    }

    private void showWirelessSettings() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Veuillez activer le service NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"));
    }

    public void onPause() {
        setDetect(0);
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        if (getDetect() != 1) {
            resolveIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {                                                                 // DETECTION NFC ET PARSING NDEF
        NdefMessage[] msgs;
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("Infos", getIntent().toString());
        Log.d("Infos", "display = " + display);
        if (getDisplay() != 1) {
            Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
            nfcButton.startAnimation(shake);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Veuillez lancer un scan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        else if ("android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED".equals(action) || "android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED".equals(action) || "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED".equals(action)) {
            setRes(1);
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES");
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            } else {
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
                Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                byte[] payload = NdefMessageParser.dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {record});
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] {msg};
            }
            if (getDisplay() == 1) {
                getResult(msgs);
            }
        }
    }

    private void getResult(NdefMessage[] msgs) {                                                            // MODAL AVEC RESULTAT DU SCAN NFC
        if (msgs != null && msgs.length != 0) {
            final StringBuilder tmp_builder = new StringBuilder();
            List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
            int size = records.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                tmp_builder.append(records.get(i).str());
                tmp_builder.append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println(tmp_builder.toString());
            this.anim.cancel();
            this.anim2.cancel();
            setDisplay(0);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Resultat du scan :");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Visiter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 /*  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RightActivity.class);
                    link = tmp_builder.toString();
                    i.putExtra("url", link);
                    startActivity(i);*/
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Copier", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Texte copié", link);
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Fermer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
            });
            builder.setMessage(tmp_builder.toString());
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }
```

That's an App to read NFC tag

Comment: Can you show some screenshots?

Comment: of my code or my app ?

EDIT : My fragment is empty

Comment: You are able to copy all of your code to fragment. Nothing needed to let it there in activity

Comment: So i let my activity totaly empty and copy/paste everything in my fragment?

Answer (score 0):

The NFC reading Framework (at least `newIntent` and the enabling of foreground dispatch) should be in the Activity as the Intent is passed to your Activity, you could then pass the Intent data received to the Fragment for processing of the actual data.

Also handling the `newIntent` in the Activity provides a better user experience, you don't really want the OS launching another screen over your app because the user brought the NFC card in to range while in a Fragment that is not doing anything with NFC. So the App always should register to handle the type of cards you want in all screens and then make a decision in the Activity if it is going to do something always with the NFC data or conditionally depending on what Fragment is active (that choice can be made in the Activity or Every Fragment). Doing that part in the Activity means less copy and paste of code to every Fragment.

The same goes for `onActivityResult`, handle initially in Activity and pass on as required to Fragments depending on how you want to handle these