# I have created a Fragment but don't know what to put inside

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have realised an NFC (to scan tags) application, but now I have to create fragment who works with my MainActivity because I'd like to implement `ViewPager` in future.

Problem is that i'm really beginner and my code became too big to know what I have to put in `Activity` and what I have to put in `Fragment`

One week that I'm trying to understand...

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ObjectAnimator anim;
    ObjectAnimator anim2;
    private int display, result, detect = 0;
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    private ImageButton nfcButton;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private ImageButton qrButton;
    private TextView text;
    private ImageButton webButton;
    String link = null;
    public final int CUSTOMIZED_REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000ffff;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        slidr = Slidr.attach(this);
        setDetect(1);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main);
        this.text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        this.nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        this.nfcButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nfc_button);
        this.anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.nfcButton, "scaleX", new float[]{0.9f});
        this.anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.nfcButton, "scaleY", new float[]{0.9f});
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        this.nfcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDisplay(1);
                manageBlinkEffect();
            }
        });
        this.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {                                   // RESULTAT DU SCAN QR CODE
        if (requestCode != CUSTOMIZED_REQUEST_CODE && requestCode != IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CUSTOMIZED_REQUEST_CODE: {
                Toast.makeText(this, "REQUEST_CODE = " + requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }

        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(resultCode, data);

        if (result.getContents() != null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Résultat du scan :");
            if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(result.getContents())) {                                                                      // si url...
                builder.setNeutralButton("Visiter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Fermer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Copier", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Texte copié", result.getContents());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                    }
                });
            } else {                                                                                                             // si plain text...
                builder.setNeutralButton("Copier", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Texte copié", result.getContents());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Fermer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
            }
            builder.setMessage(result.getContents().toString());
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }


    public void manageBlinkEffect() {                                                                           // ANIMATION DU LOGO SENZU SUITE A UN CLIC
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(9);
        anim.start();
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
                if (getRes() != 1){
                    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aucun badge n'a été détécté !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    nfcButton.startAnimation(shake);
                }
            }
        });
        anim2.setDuration(1000);
        anim2.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        anim2.setRepeatCount(9);
        anim2.start();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent(); // Recuperer l'intent actuel
        NdefMessage[] msgs;
        if (getDetect() == 1 && (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))) { // si l'application a ete lancee via une detection NFC du device  (ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, voir AndroidManifest)
            Parcelable[] rawMessages =
                    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES");
            if (rawMessages != null) { // si NDEF dans le scan
                setDisplay(1);
                resolveIntent(intent); // parser le scan NFC
            }  else {
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
                Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                byte[] payload = NdefMessageParser.dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {record});
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] {msg};
                setDetect(0);
                getResult(msgs);
            }
        }
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter2 = this.nfcAdapter;
        if (nfcAdapter2 != null) {
            if (!nfcAdapter2.isEnabled()) {
                showWirelessSettings();
            }
            this.nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, this.pendingIntent, (IntentFilter[]) null, (String[][]) null);
        }
    }

    private void showWirelessSettings() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Veuillez activer le service NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"));
    }

    public void onPause() {
        setDetect(0);
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        if (getDetect() != 1) {
            resolveIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {                                                                 // DETECTION NFC ET PARSING NDEF
        NdefMessage[] msgs;
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("Infos", getIntent().toString());
        Log.d("Infos", "display = " + display);
        if (getDisplay() != 1) {
            Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
            nfcButton.startAnimation(shake);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Veuillez lancer un scan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        else if ("android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED".equals(action) || "android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED".equals(action) || "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED".equals(action)) {
            setRes(1);
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES");
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            } else {
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
                Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                byte[] payload = NdefMessageParser.dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {record});
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] {msg};
            }
            if (getDisplay() == 1) {
                getResult(msgs);
            }
        }
    }

    private void getResult(NdefMessage[] msgs) {                                                            // MODAL AVEC RESULTAT DU SCAN NFC
        if (msgs != null && msgs.length != 0) {
            final StringBuilder tmp_builder = new StringBuilder();
            List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
            int size = records.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                tmp_builder.append(records.get(i).str());
                tmp_builder.append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println(tmp_builder.toString());
            this.anim.cancel();
            this.anim2.cancel();
            setDisplay(0);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Resultat du scan :");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Visiter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 /*  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RightActivity.class);
                    link = tmp_builder.toString();
                    i.putExtra("url", link);
                    startActivity(i);*/
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Copier", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Texte copié", link);
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Fermer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
            });
            builder.setMessage(tmp_builder.toString());
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }
```

I don't know if I have to transfert my `onResume`, `onPause` etc. in my Fragment

Really lost...

Comment: If i understand correctly, you try to learn how to use ViewPager, right?

Comment: yeah, my goal is to be able to swipe activities by sliding finger, with a great transition. Apparently, only ViewPager can do that.

Comment: This is pretty much the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302675/too-late-to-create-fragments/ which I answered. Without additional details it hard to say what should go where. You need to tell us what the all the Fragments are going to do and how you want each fragment to respond to a NFC card being presented.

Comment: I just want to swipe activities with transition... I don't know why using fragment is the only way to do that..

Comment: At the moment you only have one logical screen, that translates to 1 fragment, to swipe between fragment you need more than 1 fragment. You need to give us an idea what these other fragments are going to do and how they should behave if a NFC card is presented

Comment: Actually I have my first activity who contains a button. If clicked, the scan is enabled and when a tag is detected a modal appears to show the result content.

I'll have a second activity who just gonna contains a web page
and a third activity who gonna display and history (tags who gets scanned in the past)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should add ViewPager in XML;

Then;

In your activity define your viewpager like that;

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_main)
```

Then use this for setup viewpager

```
setupViewPager(viewPager)
```

Create setupViewPager function like that;

```
private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager) {
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(
            MainFragment(),
            "Fragment1"
        )
adapter.addFragment(
            SecondFragment(),
            "Fragment2"
        )
        viewPager.adapter = adapter}
```

Simple example of fragments;

```
class MainFragment() : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    retainInstance = true
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? =
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_screen_fragment, container, false)

/* info_screen_fragment is your xml for this fragment */
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

My codes written with Kotlin. But i used to this codes. Simple and flex.

Comment: thanks! and where to define <fragment> XML ? 
I copy/past all my code into my fragment?

Comment: R.layout.info_screen_fragment is your fragment's xml. Check MainFragment(). You dont need to copy/paste, just change info_screen_fragments instead your xml. Or in setupViewPager function, you should add your fragment instead MainFragment

Comment: so i can implement viewpager without transfert all my code into a fragment ?

Comment: if you want to transfer your code fragment to fragment, its not necassary, but you want to transfer your code activity to fragment, you have to transfer your code.

Comment: all i want is swipe between my activities with slide finger gesture :(

Comment: You want to swipe activities? or fragments? If you want to swipe activies, i dont suggest that. Maybe you can share your xml file?

Comment: do you want to something like that? Check it that gif;
https://www.programering.com/a/MTO5MjMwATY.html

Comment: yeah i want to do that with 3 activities

Comment: The best way to use Viewpager. You should add viewpager in your activity, then you create 3 fragment and transfer your code activities to fragments.

Comment: that's what i thought but I don't know how to transfert :/

i add viewpager in my 3 activities ?

Comment: Can you share your other activies? are these activies so complex? or not? Fragments and activities is similar. If your acitivies arent so complex, you can transfer easily.

Comment: For the moment the History one is totally empty, and my right activity is a webpage.
I can access it by two ways : swiping to the right from my main activity and the second way is when i scanned a NFC tag who contains an URL, it redirecting me

Comment: Do you use webview for load this webpage?

Comment: Firstly, you should fix your main activity. You have to add viewpager. Secondly create fragments classes with xmls. Then follow my codes.

Comment: yes but how to add viewpager if my app is not structured to do that ?
thanks for your help!

Comment: is it not possible to do what I want without move all my codes ? Just by using the fragment layout in my MainActivity's XML

Comment: ViewPager works with fragments. if you want to sliding all view, your activity's xml should has only viewpager. So you must create fragments and fragments has own xml for every pages. These xml's couldnt in main_activity.xml. ViewPager pagers should have own layout. So there is no way "ust by using the fragment layout in my MainActivity's XML"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make the changes in stages

I would understand how viewpager and fragments work first see https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/viewpager for a tutorial

The next stage is to create your first fragment with the `nfcButton` on it BUT not try to link it up yet with the NFC stuff.

This is because the starting point of handling NFC has to be in the Activity as you are overriding Activity methods to do this.

This is basically putting the code below in to the `onViewCreated` method of your fragment and moving the xml related to the button to the fragment's xml

```java
this.text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        this.nfcButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nfc_button);
        this.anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.nfcButton, "scaleX", new float[]{0.9f});
        this.anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.nfcButton, "scaleY", new float[]{0.9f});
        this.nfcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // setDisplay should not be used at this stage
                // setDisplay(1);
                manageBlinkEffect();
            }
        });
```

Also move the method `manageBlinkEffect()` to the fragment.

You should comment out in `getResult` as well at the moment

```java
this.anim.cancel();
this.anim2.cancel();
```

Then setup your viewpager in main xml file

The reason for commenting out these lines at the moment is that these need Activity to Fragment communication, you should understand https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Next stage is connecting you button back to the setDetect Flag (replacing the commented out `setDetect()` line)

i.e Your Fragment with the nfcButton it in has to tell the MainActivity to start processing any NFC data it gets sent

Then the MainActivity in `getResult` needs to tell the Fragment with the nfc to stop animating it's Button IF the Fragment with the button in is being displayed and and that Fragment is up and running. Again this is fragment communication from Activity to Fragment this time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll read your post few times !
But... Why is it so hard to get a transition animation between two activties..? i'm disapointed

Comment: Basically Activities are independent functioning units in Android because they can be deep linked and are transitioned by the OS and hark back to simpler times for compatibility. There are so many different ways to transition between screens that it would be impossible for the OS to support them all.

Comment: okay thanks, and about my fragment, the only thing I have to put inside is my nfc button ? 
what about the scan result etc?

Comment: For simplicity I left that in the AlertDialog as that will popup over the screen from the MainActivity. You could display the result of the NFC scan in many different ways including displaying it in the Fragment with the nfcButton in or any other fragment or Activity BUT doing so you need to send that data from the MainActivity to the other Fragment/Activity you want to display it in. Displaying it in an AlertDialog launched from the Fragment is wasted effort as it adds no benefit as the dialog is displayed over the viewpager part of the screen.